# Exclude leftnav in specific category/categories

Tags: magento, navigation, hide, categories, sidebar

Leftnav is active across all pages in my Magento site. But I want to hide it in specific category/categories.

Here is my code:

```
    $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3);
        $subcats = $cat->getChildren();

        foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid)

        {
          $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);

          if($_category->getIsActive())

           {
            $sub_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
            $sub_subcats = $sub_cat->getChildren();
            foreach(explode(',',$sub_subcats) as $sub_subCatid)
            {
                  $_sub_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_subCatid);
                  if($_sub_category->getIsActive()) {
                      echo '<li class="sub_cat"><a href="'.$_sub_category->getURL().'" title="View products for "'.$_sub_category->getName().'" category">'.$_sub_category->getName().'</a></li>';
                  }
             }
          }
        }

        ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if the above code is taken from a block file, it shouldn't have an echo or being outputting HTML directly, it should return the relevant data to the template which then builds and outputs the HTML.  If the above is a template file, it shouldn't have that much logic in there.  Templates should only have very minimal logic and instead call block methods and work with the returned data.

To answer your question, I would suggest simply defining a different page layout which excludes the left column under the design tab of the relevant categories.  If there is other content you need to maintain in the left column, I would suggest creating a new root template which excludes the relevant content and then selecting this in the same way.

Comment: Hi Hussey! Thanks for the info. If possible can you provide me with a link how I can create new root template? I'm a designer not a programmer but I can manage with help of Google. Thank you.